# Action type record to launch browser on an android nfc application

Tags: android, browser, nfc

I would like to add action to my `NDEFmessage` on the Android NFCDemo to launch the browser when I click on the URL.

I have code like this:

```
public static final byte[] SMART_POSTER_URL_NO_TEXT = 
    /**/new byte[] {
    (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x70, (byte)  0xd1,(byte) 0x01,     
    (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x67,      
    (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x63,(byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6d,
    /*the action type record*//         
    (byte) 0x11,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x61,(byte) 0x63 ,(byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x00
};
```

But this doesn't work.